# Use Shader, Objects etc. from other Projects

Tags: workflow

Just a simple question.
Is there a way to save shaders/object in blender?
Or just browse other projects and import stuff into other Projects.
I know i could open a older project, copy shader & objects but maybe there is a better way? I think i saw something like this in a youtube Video but im not sure. I think he used the asset browser or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried sticking "blender asset browser tutorial" (without the quotes) into Google?

Comment: As John says you can use the Asset Browser, you'll be able to Append or Link, and see the assets stored in libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either *Append* or *Link* all kind of data from other projects. The options are under `File`. Put simply, *Link* is basically just an external reference while *Append* creates local copies of the imported stuff.

[image]